# Is it possible to have Named Constants in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-named-ranges

Excel has a notion of defined names which can be used to define constants/literals. Does GSheets allow this?

You can see this in action in the following Excel screenshot:

[image: Excel defined name as constant example].

Cell `B2` has the formula `=A2*cm_per_inch` and via the name manager window, you can see `cm_per_inch` is a constant value of 2.54 and not a reference to a cell address.

When I import this spreadsheet into GSheets I get the following with `#NAME?` errors. Also, note in the GSheets Named ranges list there are only two entries whereas in Excel there were three. `cm_per_inch` appears to be missing, presumably because GSheets does not support a defined constant.

[image: GSheets #NAME? error when parsing Excel defined name constants]

One workaround would be to do as [this Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396208/a-constant-in-google-spreadsheet) proposes but that is more of a lookup table and not a constant as per Excel constructs. You can see this in action in a revision of the previous GSheet here:

[image: GSheet with a defined name referencing a cell with a constant value]

Of note, I wasn't able to use the `cm_per_inch` as the name of my range and had to use a new range name entirely in order for the formulae to resolve properly.

Comment: Welcome. The question isn't completely clear regarding what kind of response are you looking for.

Comment: I tried to be clear in the opening statement: "Does GSheets allow this?" where this has been defined as "defined names which can be used to define constants/literals". The rest of the question is about giving a clear example for anyone to reproduce and make sure they understand what I'm trying to accomplish? All of the answers seem to be on point for what I was expecting but the accepted one was the most comprehensive in explaining why it isn't allowed while the others gave alternatives to get around the lack of support. How might I have been more clear in the ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible in Google Sheets, because **Select data range** field can intake only cell/array references. Therefore, best you can have is to create the second sheet where you will store your variables/constants and name them with Named ranges - and then right-click the sheet and select **Hide sheet**

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

This could be also resolved by storing variables/constants into the script and then call for it like:

```
var variables = [2.54]
function cm_per_inch() {
  return variables[0];
}
```

[image: 0]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A5*cm_per_inch())
```

```
=A7*cm_per_inch()
```

Answer (score 0):

> `cm_per_inch` appears to be missing, presumably because GSheets does not support a defined constant.

You are right, Google Sheets doesn't support a defined constant as well it doesn't support other Excel features like [Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) as many others.

Please send your feedback directly to Google by using [Google Feedback](https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/).

It's worth to note that Google Sheets also have many features that are not supported on Excel like the built-in `IMAGE(url)` among others.

The alternatives are too many, from a) importing only the Excel values to b) 
 create a new spreadsheet from scratch.